# Spinning wheel when performing location.reload();

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am doing some stuff in my Javascript function and then I have to refresh the page using `location.reload();`

Is there a simple way with jQuery to show a spinning wheel from the point where the page starts to refresh to the point where the page is loaded?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there might be a solution to just wrap `.reload()` call info your own function and show spinner before it I seriously doubt the effectiveness. As soon as you issues navigational request, your browser starts killing loaded resources (that also means images) and that's when all GIF's are going to halt with animation. Well maybe not instantaneous but soon enough to spoil the effect...

Comment: is there a simple way to reload the content of the page, without reloading the page (sending a new request)?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to achieve that using `.load` function in `jQuery`. You would need to call `$('#container').load(location.href + ' #container')` where this page must contain `DIV` with `id="container"`. You can read more about it here: http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments

Answer (score 0):

If you need to avoid doing Ajax, my approach will be the following

- simply show an [animated gif as an image](http://ajaxload.info/) just before calling `location.reload();`
- always have the spinner image displayed (first item after your `<body>` tag, and hide it onload (window.onload / jQuery [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/))

there will be some flickering though...

Comment: if so, then just use $.load and get the new page... (http://api.jquery.com/load/) then show/hide the spinner on ajaxStart and ajaxStop etc... (a different question asked many times in SO, you'll find it)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Jovan Perovic you found me a solution for this..the load() seems to be very usefull to me..Thanks once again